# Is there an easy way to groupby and count row elements using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, aggregate

I want to groupby my data by day, but also get the frequency for the gender in each day.
From this:

```
NUM        DTA        GENDER
461871  07/18/2020  F
477090  09/23/2020  M
2043366 10/07/2020  F
2043366 10/24/2020  F
1627234 07/29/2020  M
... ... ...
421338  09/15/2020  M
424569  05/19/2020  M
427780  07/03/2020  M
427780  09/05/2020  M
2180672 09/03/2020  F
```

To something like this:

```
   DTA           F        M
05/01/2020      123      79
05/02/2020      89       100
05/03/2020      94       88
05/04/2020      101      76
05/05/2020      98       90
05/06/2020      87       65
05/07/2020      111      72
```

I've tried this code, but can't reach to any satisfying results.

```
d_visits_gen.groupby(["DTA",'GENDER']).agg({'GENDER':'count'}).rename(columns={"GENDER" : 'count'})
```

Comment: `pd.crosstab(df['DTA'], df['GENDER'])`.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!